# Spring Integration <inbound-channel-adapter> Rabbit MQ getting disconnected

Tags: spring, integration, rabbitmq, spring-integration

We are working on a POC to use Spring integration and Rabbit MQ. 
We have two modules producer module and consumer module both are runs in different JVMs.
The Producer module listen on a Folder (input folder) as soon as new files arrives,  creates a message then push to (incoming.q.in) queue and also move to process folder.

The Consumer module then pickups the messages from the incoming.q.in Queue then process the files them move to complete folder.

Both Producer and Consumer code is working fine but after some ideal item then consumer module is getting disconnecting from Rabbit MQ. We see messages in incoming.q.in queue but the consumer is not processing.

When I logged into Rabbit MQ Admin/Management tool “incoming.q.in” consumer list is empty and the message is “... no consumers ...”.
  The consumer code

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inBoundfile" queue-names="incoming.q.in" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    error-channel="error.in">
</int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="inBoundfile" output-channel="serviceInbound">
    <int:header name="FILEID" expression="payload.fileID" />
</int:header-enricher>
<int:service-activator ref="routerService" method="processFile" input-channel="serviceInbound" output-channel="fileHandler.router.in" />
....
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on DEBUG logging on the consumer side; you'll see lots of logging and reconnection attempts if/when a connection is lost.

Comment: Gary ..Thanks for suggestion.  

At present I have 11 messages in queue. 
The consumer is running but In Rabbit MQ Console the consumer list is empty.

I have full of below messages.
.....
.....
[07/22/13 07:06:56:056 EDT] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-Qc6H2e-XJOspKRmYdoEcwU], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@10.106.230.151:80/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
.....
.....

Comment: The environment is clustered based environment multiple Rabbit MQ servers running. I am accessing using load balance URL.

Comment: Are you using HA queues? Have you looked at connections on the other brokers?

Comment: Yes we are using HA Queues. On All nodes the consumers list is empty for that queue. Connections are at running state.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - if you are seeing lots of those `retrieving` messages then all is working fine; you won't see those messages if there's no consumer.

Comment: Gary... Then why the messages were not deleted from Queue. Do I need to any thing different for HA Queues? -- Thank You,

Comment: I can't explain that; you'll need to do some more analysis - all I am saying is that if you see those messages, you have a channel and are receiving messages and the container is acking them. There is no special configuration needed in Spring for HA. You probably need to move this discussion to the RabbitMQ mailing list; I don't believe there is a problem with Spring, here.